# Qt signal and slot issue

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals

I have an issue with my signals and slots, I want to use a backgroundworker which is an extra thread. Its suppose to send a signal with a few double values which should then be updated in the main gui. Well the code compiles and the thread starts also but the gui is not updating the values.

first the gui slot:

```
void MainWindow::slot_set_values(double ptm_temp, double ptm_hv, double heat_temp, double nomtemp, double current, double voltage)
{
    ui->pmtValueLabel->setText(QString::number(ptm_temp));
    ui->hvValueLabel->setText(QString::number(ptm_hv));
    ui->heatValueLabel->setText(QString::number(heat_temp));
    ui->nomValueLabel->setText(QString::number(nomtemp));
    ui->currenValueLabel->setText(QString::number(current));
    ui->vValueLabel->setText(QString::number(voltage));

}
```

the worker code:

```
void dworker::run()
{
    qsrand(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t());
    mData.set_pmt_temp(qrand()%100);
    mData.set_pmt_hv(qrand()%100);
    mData.set_heat_opt_temp(qrand()%100);
    mData.set_heat_nominal_temp(qrand()%100);

    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        double pmt_tmp = mData.get_pmt_temp();
        double hv = mData.get_pmt_hv();
        double heat_temp = mData.get_heat_opt_temp();
        double heat_nom = mData.get_heat_nominal_temp();

        emit set_values(pmt_tmp,hv,heat_temp,heat_nom,0,0);
        emit set_pmt();

        QThread::msleep(1000);
        qDebug() << "Test vom Thread " << i;
    }
}
```

and the connect statements:

```
connect(workerthread,SIGNAL(set_values(double,double,double,double,double,double)),
this,SLOT(slot_set_values(double,double,double,double,double,double)));

connect(workerthread,SIGNAL(set_pmt()),this,SLOT(slot_set_pmt()));
```

Comment: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: What is the dWorker class? Is it a class you've derived and if so, have you remembered to include the Q_OBJECT macro? Also, when running in a debugger, what output do you get when it passes the connect lines? If there's a problem, it will tell you there.

Comment: Have you tried adding a qDebug statement in your slot to see if it being called?

Comment: i included a qDebug statment and it is beeing called but wont set the text to what i want :-( the dworker class is derived from QThread.

Comment: @SeriousSammy Not exactly related to your problem, but when you are creating a worker thread, don't subclass `QThread`. Subclass `QObject` instead. `QThread` is used for managing threads, not processing data. [Read this for more info](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20691)

Comment: Thank you, i read the article from Huytard and changed it to Object and now pass it via worker->moveToThread to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If object that sends signal and receiver object are in a different threads, you should connect it with `Qt::QueuedConnection` (docs [here](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum))

So, change you connects to this:

```
connect(workerthread,SIGNAL(set_values(double,double,double,double,double,double)), this,SLOT(slot_set_values(double,double,double,double,double,double)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(workerthread,SIGNAL(set_pmt()),this,SLOT(slot_set_pmt()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Additionally, you can try to check via qDebug, what are you receiving in the slot:

```
qDebug()<<"my slot is called,"<<ptm_temp<<" "<<ptm_hv<<" "<<heat_temp<<" "<<nomtemp<<" "<<current<<" "<<voltage;
```

Also, it is imperative to have signal-slots, that in header of your derived class was `Q_OBJECT` macro